# Depth First Search problems

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

http://usacotraining.blogspot.com/2013/10/problem-142-clocks.html
I am attempting to use Depth First Search to solve this problem. I created a Node class based on a 3x3 array, and am using a visited array of size 4^9. However, this clearly is not working at all (it is not printing anything). My attempts of debugging (see comments) showed me that for some reason the array seems to be resetting each time, but I cannot figure out why.

Also, I am sure that my code is unnecessarily complicated, and there is a better way to perform DFS like this. Can someone show me a better way?

```
/*
ID: akshajk1
LANG: JAVA
TASK: clocks
*/
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;
class clocks {
    public static boolean[] visited;
    public static boolean done;
    public static String[] moves = {"ABDE", "ABC", "BCEF", "ADG", "BDEFH", "CFI", "DEGH", "GHI", "EFHI"};
    public static Stack<Integer> ans = new Stack<Integer>();
    public static Stack<Integer> finalans = new Stack<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)); 
        // BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("clocks.in"));
        // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("clocks.out"));
        // int n = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());

        int[][] a = new int[3][3]; 
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(bf.readLine());
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++) a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        visited = new boolean[4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4];
        Node x = new Node(a);
        dfs(x);
        for(int i : finalans) 
            out.println(i + " ");

        out.close(); System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void dfs(Node a) {
        if(done) return;
        int n = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                n = 4*n+a.get(i, j);
        if(visited[n]) return;
        // for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { for(int j=0; j<3; j++) System.out.print(a.get(i,  j)); System.out.print("\n"); } System.out.print("\n");
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans.toArray()) + "\n");
        boolean gotit = true;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) for(int j=0; j<3; j++) if(a.get(i, j) != 0) gotit = false;
        if(gotit) {
            for(int i : ans)
                finalans.push(i);
            done = true;
            return;
        }
        visited[n] = true;
        for(int i=0; i<moves.length; i++) {
            char[] x = moves[i].toCharArray();
            int[][] b = new int[3][3];
            for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
                for(int kk=0; kk<3; kk++)
                    b[k][kk] = a.get(k, kk);
            Node abc = new Node(b);
            for(char c : x) 
                abc = abc.turn(c);
            ans.push((i+1));
            dfs(abc);
        }           
        ans.pop();
    }
}
class Node {
    final private int[][] a;
    public Node(int[][] aaa) {
        a = new int[3][3];
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                a[i][j] = aaa[i][j];
    }
    public int get(int i, int j) { 
        return (a[i][j] % 12)/3;
    }
    public Node turn(char c) {
        int val = c - 'A';
        int[][] b = new int[3][3];
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        b[val/3][val%3] += 3;
        if(b[val/3][val%3] > 12) b[val/3][val%3] %= 12;
        if(b[val/3][val%3] == 0) b[val/3][val%3] += 12;
        Node ansans = new Node(b);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { for(int j=0; j<3; j++) System.out.print(ansans.get(i,  j)); System.out.print("\n"); } System.out.print("\n");

        return ansans;
    }
}
```

edit: Thanks for all the help! I was able to correct the copying bug, and now the print statements make more sense, but the program is still stopping after performing move 1 four times. I changed the visited array to mark the initial value as true, resulting in the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;
class clocks {
    public static boolean[] visited;
    public static boolean done;
    public static String[] moves = {"ABDE", "ABC", "BCEF", "ADG", "BDEFH", "CFI", "DEGH", "GHI", "EFHI"};
    public static Stack<Integer> ans = new Stack<Integer>();
    public static Stack<Integer> finalans = new Stack<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)); 
        // BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("clocks.in"));
        // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("clocks.out"));
        // int n = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());

        int[][] a = new int[3][3]; 
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(bf.readLine());
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++) a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        visited = new boolean[4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4];
        Node x = new Node(a);
        int n = 0;
        for(int xx=0; xx<3; xx++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                n = 4*n+x.get(xx, j);
        visited[n] = true;
        dfs(x);
        for(int i : finalans) 
            out.println(i + " ");

        out.close(); System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void dfs(Node a) {

        if(done) return;
        // for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { for(int j=0; j<3; j++) System.out.print(a.get(i,  j)); System.out.print("\n"); } System.out.print("\n");
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans.toArray()) + "\n");
        boolean gotit = true;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) for(int j=0; j<3; j++) if(a.get(i, j) != 0) gotit = false;
        if(gotit) {
            for(int i : ans)
                finalans.push(i);
            done = true;
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<moves.length; i++) {
            char[] x = moves[i].toCharArray();
            int[][] b = new int[3][3];
            for(int k=0; k<3; k++) {
                for(int kk=0; kk<3; kk++) {
                    b[k][kk] = a.get(k, kk)*3;
                    if(b[k][kk] == 0) b[k][kk] = 12;
                }
            }
            Node abc = new Node(b);
            for(char c : x) 
                abc = abc.turn(c);
            int n = 0;
            for(int xx=0; xx<3; xx++)
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                    n = 4*n+abc.get(xx, j);
            if(!visited[n]) { 
                visited[n] = true;
                ans.push((i+1));
                dfs(abc);
                ans.pop();
            }
        }           
    }
}
class Node {
    final private int[][] a;
    public Node(int[][] aaa) {
        a = new int[3][3];
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                a[i][j] = aaa[i][j];
    }
    public int get(int i, int j) { 
        return (a[i][j] % 12)/3;
    }
    public Node turn(char c) {
        int val = c - 'A';
        int[][] b = new int[3][3];
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        b[val/3][val%3] += 3;
        if(b[val/3][val%3] > 12) b[val/3][val%3] %= 12;
        if(b[val/3][val%3] == 0) b[val/3][val%3] += 12;
        Node ansans = new Node(b);
        // for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { for(int j=0; j<3; j++) System.out.print(ansans.get(i,  j)); System.out.print("\n"); } System.out.print("\n");

        return ansans;
    }
}
```

(I also fixed another bug). This for some reason is still not working, and is yielding a stack overflow error. I understand that there is a lot of recursion, but only a maximum of 9*3 = 27 moves should be made anyways. Why is this happening?

Comment: Where exactly is the array resetting?

Comment: I don't know; that is the problem.

Comment: In your IDE, place breakpoints and then run the code in debug mode. This will allow you to see the variables at every line before the line is executed. Do this and see if you can find exactly where your code is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Your copying is wrong. The line where you copy a to b. You set each oft b's values to a.get(i, j) where a.get() does not return its value but value%12 divided by 3.

Ok i figured out that for the first 6000 searches (thats when your ans-stack overflows) the algorithm always has a valid move to choose.

To prevent that you should consider breadth first search or set a maximum search depth.

I´ve added a maximum search depth and the algorithm returns, however the turns required change from situation to situation and range over a large set. Therefore sometimes 200 moves are required, so you can´t set a maximum search depth of any lower value. But then with 200 as maximum search depth. Any 200 step solution will be accepted even if better solutions exist.

My recommendation therefore is to take depth first search as your search algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having trouble though, please see my edited post